# Why does my laptop overheat and slow down even when I'm doing light things?

Tags: cooling

Here's my spec.

```
System   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Manufacturer Hewlett-Packard 
  Model HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC 
  Total amount of system memory 4.00 GB RAM 
  System type 64-bit operating system 
  Number of processor cores 2 

Storage   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Total size of hard disk(s) 466 GB 
  Disk partition (C:) 123 GB Free (444 GB Total) 
  Disk partition (D:) 3 GB Free (21 GB Total) 
  Disk partition (E:) 90 MB Free (99 MB Total) 
  Media drive (F:) CD/DVD 
  Media drive (G:) CD 

Graphics   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Display adapter type ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 
  Total available graphics memory 2202 MB 
        Dedicated graphics memory 512 MB 
        Dedicated system memory 0 MB 
        Shared system memory 1690 MB 
  Display adapter driver version 8.771.1.0 
  Primary monitor resolution 1366x768 
  DirectX version DirectX 10
```

[image: Heat]

The laptop is placed on a plain table, but becomes extremely hot when I'm just running chrome. It gets as high as 80 degrees Celsius when I'm gaming. What's wrong? Anyway I can cool it down? And I use switchable graphics cards; an intel and an amd.

I have a feeling it was overclocked from the factory, because the graphics card which isn't that strong can run games like GTA IV at 25 FPS.

**EDIT** Added HWMonitor Image

[image]

Comment: How old is it and has it always been like this? Can you hear fans kicking once it has warmed up? Can you try http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html HWMonitor to tell us if you can get any more readings because I can't see the GPU temperature or fan speeds.

Comment: @James It's 10 Months old. Its been like this for as far I as know.  A fan is always making noise. 1 fan. I've added the HWMonitor image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most obvious reason: one or more fans is either not working or only partly working. Most obvious solution: warranty repair. I'd be very cautious about trying to work on it yourself because you risk voiding the warranty: call HP first.